# get unique objects from 2 array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have 2 array of objects:

```
marketingCarriers: 
[
   {
     code: "AM"
     logo: "logo1.png"
     name: "AEROMEXICO"
   }
]

operatingCarriers: 
[
  {
    code: "DL"
    logo: "logo12.png"
    name: "DELTA"
  },
  {
    code: "AM"
    logo: "logo1.png"
    name: "AEROMEXICO"
  }
]
```

I want to make an array by comparing these two array of objects where I will put the unique objects from these 2 arrays.
So the output will be:

```
newArray: 
    [
      {
        code: "DL"
        logo: "logo12.png"
      }
    ]
```

What should be the process?

Comment: what is unique among all these objects

Comment: a for loop within a for loop probably

Comment: What have you attempted so for? Where are you stuck at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const operators = operatingCarriers.filter(operating =>
        marketingCarriers.some(marketing => marketing.code !== operating.code),
      );
    
      const hasUniqueCarriers =
        JSON.stringify(operatingCarriers) !== JSON.stringify(marketingCarriers);

{hasUniqueCarriers && operators.length > 0 && (
            <div className="flight__operating-carrier-info">
              <div>{I18n.t('components.flight_info.operated_by')}</div>
              <div className="flight__operating-carrier-list">
                {operators.map(carrier => (
                  <div>{carrier.name}</div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
```